# Do Javascript changes to the DOM affect the print version of a page?

Tags: javascript, printing

There is a page that I need to do sorting via Javascript.

If I do such sorting, and then the user decides to print the page, will the original DOM be printed or the updated DOM?

I could see it being the original DOM, as it reloads the page, and then applies the @media print styles, or I could also see it simply switching the CSS for the page.

If there is a difference between browsers, I really only care about Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Why don't you try it? Though I believe it will print the DOM at the point in time where print is accessed.

Comment: I'm currently exploring possibilities with the task I've been given.  I'd like to know what is possible before I actually write the code?

Comment: It seems really simple. Print a sample HTML page, open inspector, change some stuff around, hit print again... You could literally try this on any page.

Comment: There is only the DOM; there's not an "original DOM" and a copy of same delta the changes you make, at least AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both Chrome and FF you see the updated DOM in the print preview and in Chrome's network tab, no new interaction with the server is logged.

http://jsfiddle.net/zLL4814s/

```
<h1 id="headerTag">Hello</h1>

<button onclick="changeText()">click to change text</button>
```

js

```
window.changeText = function() {
    document.getElementById('headerTag').innerHTML = "Bye";
    window.print();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup. If we print a page, what gets printed is essentially the content of a viewport, differing only from the browser view if there exist media queries for better-styled printing (e.g. `@media print {  }`).

That said, making sure your page is printable takes some TLC, especially if the UI is of non-trivial complexity. Typically, if there's a page that someone in HR might someday want to print because it has charts, data, &etc, it's usually enough to just `display: none;` all but the interesting component(s) on the page using media queries.